# redhat-release requirement when installing Ambari on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to install Ambari on Ubuntu. I am following these steps:

http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP1/HDP-1.2.0/bk_using_Ambari_book/content/ambari-chap2.1.2.html

When I try to install the epel repository I get the following error message:

Error: Package: epel-release-6-7.noarch (HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.15) 
Requires: redhat-release >= 6

Error: Package: epel-release-6-7.noarch (HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.15)
Requires: /bin/sh

Therefore, when I check: `yum repolist` I do find `AMBARI-1.x` and `HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.15` in the repository but not the `epel` which seems to be what went wrong (or the reason why it went wrong).

I would be very grateful for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Please try the latest Ambari release (1.6.1). Looks like you are trying to use AMbari 1.2.0 and epel requirement was dropped a while ago.

http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-1.6.1.0/index.html